online experiment in Psychopy/Javascript - character limit on user input results in weird bug
I created a simple experiment using the software Psychopy (a user interface which allows non-coders like me to create experiments in Python). It can also automatically convert the entire experiment to Javascript which allows the experiment to be run online by anyone.
In the experiment, participants see an object on screen and have to type in its name. I want to limit participant input to 50 characters. Here is the small block of code I added to my experiment to limit user input to 50 chars, and the Java code automatically created by Psychopy for the online experiment:

When running this locally using the Python version, it works as intended: once the 50 char limit is reached, no further text can be inputted (unless you backspace).
However, when running this online, the program has a weird bug whereby when the 50 chars is reached, the cursor moves back to the start. Any further text input overwrites what was initially there, but also starts mixing up the order of input. For example, here is what happens when I type in ‘ball’ repeatedly:

Once the character limit is reached:

Without any knowledge of Javascript, I have no idea what is causing this and how to fix it.
I would really appreciate any help anyone can give me. Here is a longer excerpt of the Javascript code, in case it is useful:
var max_char_limit;
function showImageRoutineEachFrame() {
  return async function () {
    //--- Loop for each frame of Routine 'showImage' ---
    // get current time
    t = showImageClock.getTime();
    frameN = frameN + 1;// number of completed frames (so 0 is the first frame)
    // update/draw components on each frame
    
    // *object1* updates
    if (t >= 0.0 && object1.status === PsychoJS.Status.NOT_STARTED) {
      // keep track of start time/frame for later
      object1.tStart = t;  // (not accounting for frame time here)
      object1.frameNStart = frameN;  // exact frame index
      
      object1.setAutoDraw(true);
    }
    
    
    // *textPrompt* updates
    if (t >= 0.0 && textPrompt.status === PsychoJS.Status.NOT_STARTED) {
      // keep track of start time/frame for later
      textPrompt.tStart = t;  // (not accounting for frame time here)
      textPrompt.frameNStart = frameN;  // exact frame index
      
      textPrompt.setAutoDraw(true);
    }
    
    
    // *textbox* updates
    if (t >= 0.0 && textbox.status === PsychoJS.Status.NOT_STARTED) {
      // keep track of start time/frame for later
      textbox.tStart = t;  // (not accounting for frame time here)
      textbox.frameNStart = frameN;  // exact frame index
      
      textbox.setAutoDraw(true);
    }
    
    // Run 'Each Frame' code from checkLength
    max_char_limit = 50;
    if ((textbox_text.length > max_char_limit)) {
        textbox.text = textbox.text.slice(0, max_char_limit);
    }
    
    
    // *continue_image8* updates
    if (((textbox.text.length > 0)) && continue_image8.status === PsychoJS.Status.NOT_STARTED) {
      // keep track of start time/frame for later
      continue_image8.tStart = t;  // (not accounting for frame time here)
      continue_image8.frameNStart = frameN;  // exact frame index
      
      continue_image8.setAutoDraw(true);
    }


Thanks!
I tried using 'substring' rather than 'slice', but this resulted in the same effect.

Let's start with that being Javascript, not Java. They are two completely different languages.

Thank you @GuyIncognito. I have edited my response. Do you happen to know what is causing the issue?

Changing the input field text manually resets the cursor position. If it's possible to change the HTML, the easiest fix is to set the maxlength="50" attribute in the corresponding  tag. If not, add textbox.setSelectionRange(50, 50); after the line that says textbox.text = textbox.text.slice(0, max_char_limit);
